# Can I configure a RAID 1 on the Dell Poweredge 860 with the onboard SATA Controller

Tags: raid, software-raid, dell-poweredge, raid-controller, hardware

Is there a way to set up a RAID 1 with two SATA HDD on a DELL Poweredge 860 that has no specific RAID Controller? I want to use the on board SATA controller to set up my RAID 1.

Comment: What OS will you be running?

Comment: *Hardware* RAID without a controller? Nope. *Software* RAID without a controller? Probably, depends on the OS.

Comment: I will install windows server 2008 RC 2. So i know to setup a software raid in windows. but i'd like to install the windows into  the raid (means after i have setup the raid-array).

I'm not sure if the mainboard of the server offers me the posibility to setup a raid without a specific hardware controller.

Answer (score 1):

Self answer by David:

> So thanks for the comments, I will stop there trying to set up my RAID
>   1 on this machine.
>
> For any further question to this topic, this excerpt from the Dell
>   hardware specification of this machine will be my answer :-)
>
> - C1 MOTHERBOARD SATA CABLED, NO RAID, 1 H

Comment: So why do you not set up a software raid1?

Answer (score 1):

no, he's talking about a 'built-in' firmware raid from the motherboard.
NO, sorry that is not possible.
You might be able to do software raid AFTER you load the o/s, using OMSA.